# Issue with Resizeable Columns in YUI2 DataTable Nested in YUI3 Tabview

Tags: yui, yui-datatable, yui3, yui2

I'm having an issue with resizing columns in a YUI2 DataTable when the table is nested inside a YUI3 Tabview.

My situation:

- YUI3 Tabview has 4 tabs.
- Each tab contains a DataTable that has sortable and resizable columns.
- The columns in the DataTable of the first tab (the default tab that is displayed after loading the tab view) are sortable AND resizable and work as expected.
- The columns in DataTables in the other three tabs are sortable BUT NOT resizeable.

I'm able to see in firebug that the DataTables in the other tabs have the same innerHTML structure, classes, etc in the  elements.

I'm happy to post code samples but I thought I'd just start with this basic question to see if anyone has ideas or suggestions for how I can debug this issue.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Bart

Comment: If possible, Try To use http://jsbin.com To reproduce your scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem locally. Can you post a repro case?

Here's what worked for me: http://gist.github.com/501137

jenny

Comment: Jenny, Thanks for taking the time to put this example together.  I ended up getting an answer to this issue on the YUI Library forum.  The link is here: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=3337&p=15606#p15606